# How to make rounded corner bars in google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

> I have following chart with square bars

[image]

> I want it to make rounded corner bars with google charts like below pic

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are no standard [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) to change the shape of the column

but you can modify the svg directly when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

however, the chart will revert back to the original shape, on any other event

so need to modify, anytime an event is fired
--> `'ready'`, `'select'`, `'onmouseover'`, `'onmouseout'`

to change the border radius of a `rect` element, use the attributes `rx` and `ry`

to ensure we have the correct `rect` elements,
custom `colors` are provided to the chart
then the `fill` attribute is checked, to see if it exists in `colors`

`rect` elements with a `fill` attribute of `'none'` are also included,
this will be the `rect` used to highlight the column `'onmouseover'`

as well as `rect` elements with a `stroke` attribute of `'#ffffff'`,
which are used to mark the selected column

one other note, the svg appears to change any `colors` to lower case,
so lower case `colors` are used in the array

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', '2015', '2016'],
      ['Jan', 10, 15],
      ['Feb', 12, 18],
      ['Mar', 14, 21],
      ['Apr', 16, 24]
    ]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

    var colors = ['#cd6155', '#5499c7'];

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', changeBorderRadius);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', changeBorderRadius);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', changeBorderRadius);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', changeBorderRadius);

    function changeBorderRadius() {
      chartColumns = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartColumns, function(column) {
        if ((colors.indexOf(column.getAttribute('fill')) > -1) ||
            (column.getAttribute('fill') === 'none') ||
            (column.getAttribute('stroke') === '#ffffff')) {
          column.setAttribute('rx', 20);
          column.setAttribute('ry', 20);
        }
      });
    }

    chart.draw(data, {
      colors: colors
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat, i did same thing by setting attribute of rect using jquery on various events of chart.