# How to create custom bar chart using google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I want to create bar chart using google charts 
Condition to create chart is like Bar should have fixed width and padding between the bars and it should be plot at center of grid lines.

I used google chart for this .

```
 google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
    ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
    ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
    ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
    ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc:  getValueAt.bind(undefined, 1),
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    bar: {
        groupWidth: 20
    },
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
   }
   function getValueAt(column, dataTable, row) {
    return dataTable.getFormattedValue(row, column);
  }
```

[JsFiddle for the same](https://jsfiddle.net/6x2y35gn/7/)

I want to create something like this.

[image: Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get the bars between the gridlines,
will need to use a continuous data type for the x-axis,
`timeofday` will work, which takes an array of either 3 or 4 numbers,
representing hours, minutes, seconds, and optionally milliseconds, respectively

```
['Time', 'Value'],
[[9, 30, 0], 20],
[[10, 30, 0], 30],
...
```

set the data values at the half minute mark,
then use `ticks` at the full minute mark...

```
ticks: [
  [9, 0, 0],
  [10, 0, 0],
  ...
```

for padding between the bars, use a percentage...

```
bar: {
  groupWidth: '95%'
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Value'],
    [[9, 30, 0], 20],
    [[10, 30, 0], 30],
    [[11, 30, 0], 57],
    [[12, 30, 0], 70],
    [[13, 30, 0], 80],
    [[14, 30, 0], 55],
    [[15, 30, 0], 45],
    [[16, 30, 0], 20],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    },
    role: 'annotation',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      stem: {
        color: '#cb4335',
        length: 20,
      },
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    colors: ['#cb4335'],
    hAxis: {
      format: 'ha',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      ticks: [
        [9, 0, 0],
        [10, 0, 0],
        [11, 0, 0],
        [12, 0, 0],
        [13, 0, 0],
        [14, 0, 0],
        [15, 0, 0],
        [16, 0, 0],
      ],
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_values'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to expand the gridlines, use option `hAxis.viewWindow.min` & `max`

and `chartArea.width` can extend the chart to the edges of the chart container

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Value'],
    [[9, 30, 0], 20],
    [[10, 30, 0], 30],
    [[11, 30, 0], 57],
    [[12, 30, 0], 70],
    [[13, 30, 0], 80],
    [[14, 30, 0], 55],
    [[15, 30, 0], 45],
    [[16, 30, 0], 20],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    },
    role: 'annotation',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      alwaysOutside: true,
      stem: {
        color: '#cb4335',
        length: 20,
      },
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '95%'
    },
    chartArea: {
      width: '100%'
    },
    colors: ['#cb4335'],
    hAxis: {
      format: 'ha',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      ticks: [
        [9, 0, 0],
        [10, 0, 0],
        [11, 0, 0],
        [12, 0, 0],
        [13, 0, 0],
        [14, 0, 0],
        [15, 0, 0],
        [16, 0, 0],
      ],
      viewWindow: {
        min: [6, 0, 0],
        max: [20, 0, 0]
      }
    },
    height: 400,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_values'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values"></div>
```

Comment: how can i expand grid lines left and right side and tooltip should appear out of grid lines @WhiteHat,  This solution is pretty much closer to the ask

Comment: see __EDIT__ above, as for annotations, you can increase `stem.length`, but won't extend above gridlines or be the same for each bar -- the solution above [is mine as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38721880/5090771), up votes greatly appreciated...